# How to configure grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Hi Friends Myself Mukesh and I want your help to solve my problem.
I have installed Ubuntu 14 on my HCL desktop with legacy BIOS support.  It was working fine till yesterday when I installed windows 8 on the same system to make dual boot.  My Ubuntu would not boot but windows 8 was working fine, so I installed grub with Ubuntu Live Disk Support, with the command line As below:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

After this, Grub shows Ubuntu to load but it does not hav an option for Windows8 to load.  So now Ubuntu is working fine but I am not able to start Windows8.  How can I edit Grub To boot both from Ubuntu And Windows 8?

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: install this on Ubuntu, [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Solved!

Answer (score 1):

As grub does not natively support DOS based boot, you will either need to set up a truly complicated install setup, with a lot of chain loading, or you can just install burg, which supports as many OSs as I have ever tried with it. Use this to install it:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes

Plus it supports themes, some really awesome ones out of the box too!

Comment: If I solved your problem, go ahead and mark it as solved, don't worry it's reversible if someone gives a better one :)